# gitosis auto merge hook

Tags: git, git-merge, gitosis

I'm trying to auto-merge between two stable branches using gitosis hooks.

I've found an [article](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/git-automatic-merges-with-server-side-hooks-for-the-win/) that describes how to do this using just git hooks.

I'm just uncertain how to do the same thing using gitosis, any thoughts?

Essentially, a successful commit to **maint** branch would auto merge into **dev** branch.

Answer (score 0):

Git hooks are not specific to a particular git server (like Atlassian Stash). They can always be found in the repository, in the `.git/hooks` folder.

To get a server side hook, log in to the server and alter the contents of `/home/git/repositories/<repo>/hooks` (since gitosis puts the repos under `/home/git`) . There are already samples there, with the suffix `.sample`. Remove the suffix (and make them executable) and they will work. Use them as a starting point and try the stuff suggested in the article.

(Disclaimer: Since I haven't got gitosis set up, I haven't tried this myself)